# Run a new container based on currently running container

Tags: docker

I am able to run a container by running

`docker run --name nginx-base -p 81:81 -d nginx`

How do I use this same container but run it in port 80 and add a volume link to it such as:

`docker start nginx-base -p 80:80 -v mydomain:/etc/nginx/site-available/mydomain`

Comment: Do you mean a new container with that parameters or the same container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same image to launch another container on the port 80, with such a command

`docker run --name nginx80 -p 80:80 -d nginx`

as long as you use different ports and names for your container, you can go on, such as

`docker run --name nginx83 -p 83:83 -d nginx`

Consider that an image can't be updated (we will forget `docker commit`), but the Dockerfile, the way to recreate an updated/modified image, helps you create easily another image.

The doc for `docker commit` if needed

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

You can have a reference Dockerfile, so you build your image with such a command

`docker build -t myuser/myproject:0.1 .`

and a modified Dockerfile, such as Dockerfile_mod1, and you build another image using this Dockerfile, with a command such as

`docker build -t myuser/mymodifiedproject:0.12 -f Dockerfile_mod1 .`

but you should have a Dockerfile and rebuild as often as needed a modifed image.

Comment: so this is the docker flow, this is what i need, thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only use `docker run` to start a new container. And of course, with another container name.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run --name nginx-base -p 80:80 -v mydomain:/etc/nginx/site-available/mydomain -d nginx
```